# Proof If a tree is not trivial, then there are at least two pendant vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following Proof but could not understand it

Proof. If a tree has $n(≥ 2)$ vertices, then the sum of the degrees is $2(n − 1)$. If every vertex has a $degree ≥ 2$, then the sum will be $≥ 2n $. On the other hand, if all but one vertex have degree $≥ 2$, then the sum would be $≥ 1 + 2(n − 1) = 2n − 1$.
I do not understand why: *the sum would be* $≥1+2(n−1)=2n−1$

Answer (score 1):

One vertex has degree $\ge 1$ (because the tree is connected), the other $n-1$ vertices have degree $\ge 2$ each.